# Show $\sqrt[3]{2}\notin F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose that $F$ is the infinite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ obtained by adjoining the square root of every integer (positive or negative). I'm trying to show that $\sqrt[3]{2}\notin F$. I have no idea how to prove it. Anyone can help me?

Comment: I guess you have to say that beside $F$ being an infinite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$,  if $a \in F$ then there is some $n$ such that $a \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1},\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}, \ldots,\sqrt{n})$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$F$ is the union of adjoining of finitely many quadratic extension which have degree over $\mathbb{Q} $ a power of 2. Then your element must be in one of those finite adjoining, but it has degree 3 over $\mathbb{Q} $ and that's impossible

Comment: Is "grade" means "degree"? I never see this word in my textbook. Can you define it?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry but in italian they have the same translation,  I'll correct